# What is the notification that pops at the bottom on Android called and how do you add it on React Native?

Tags: android, react-native

I mean this notification that many apps use:

[image]

The "Your download was resumed" box.

What is it called and how do you add it on RN?

I tried to look for notifications and alerts but that didn't bring it up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called a 'Toast' and you can use [`ToastAndroid`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/toastandroid.html) to create it on Android.

```
ToastAndroid.show('A pikachu appeared nearby !', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Hello Kuhaku,**

First thing is that `Your download was resumed` is not notification its a **Toast** in android.

If you want to display message like above screen in native [Go through with this link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-simple-toast)

**Hope this will help you.**